# Create a new tab in Case screen with grid from new user table

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add a new tab to Case Screen next to Relations tab with a grid of the newly created user table.
I have create a new DAC class and also modified CR306000.aspx form. However, tab appears but not the grid.
Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: What is name of the tab? Describe how you try to add it ?

Comment: "Activities" is the name of new tab which I am trying to add. I have directly modified the CR306000.aspx form and I was able to see the tab being added. Now I want to add the grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remember that:

- Each asp.net page must contain a single PXDateSource control.
- The TypeName property of the PXDataSource is always the graph for the page.  In this case CRCaseMaint
- No need for you to change or add any new data source to your page.
- Since you will be extending the CRCaseMain graph, inside your extension you can simply declare Activities2 data view with standard  public PXSelect< YOURDAC > Activities2;
- In your aspx page, you can then access your dataview view through the original source with datamember set to your new view (Activities2)

Comment: Thank you for below points. I have exactly followed those but seems grid is not accepting PXGraphExtension, instead it requires PXGraph. Giving "Type *** must inherit PX.Data.PXGraph type" error when I try to bind with PXGraphExtension.

Comment: This is what I have done to implement the solutions what I need.

• Create separate PXGraph class 
• Added view to my DAC
• Added second datasource to CR306000 screen and bind it to grid.

This seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Acumatica team itself created tab "Activities". By default tab "Activities" is hidden. The same happens with your tab.

Comment: Thanks Yura. However, I want to create a new extra tab (may be I can name it as "MyActivities"). Is there anyother way to add the tab other than I added and how do I add grid with my user table fields.

Comment: Yes, you can create other tab, just call it "Activities [your company name]" or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Create separate PXGraph class 
Added view to my DAC 
Added second datasource to CR306000 screen and bind it to grid